# Not showing MySQL databases after upgrading Version 5.6 to Version 5.7

Tags: mysql

As per the instructions given in below MySQL documentation, I have upgraded(in-place) MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7 version.

[MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html)

I am able to start the DB and seeing new version as result of status, but not showing the already existing databases. Is there anything I need to do to show the databases with new version?

Fixed by adding the below lines in my.ini file after **[mysqld]**

```
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
datadir=C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\data
```

Comment: Check your new MySQL configuration to make sure it is using the same data path as the older version. If it is not then change it and (probably) re-run instruction in [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html)

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks for your input. Just now noticed that it is referring data dir as ** C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ ** , but data exits in ** C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ **. Is there anything to tweak the configuration to refer the ProgramData folder.

Comment: --datadir=dir_name. This option was removed in MySQL 5.7.2.

Comment: That's the CLI option , you should probably still find the settings in my.conf (linux) or my.ini (windows) .

Comment: After renamed the my-default.ini to my.ini in new binaries folder (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6) and added the below lines after the [mysqld]. able to see the databases.  early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
datadir=C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After renamed the my-default.ini to my.ini in new binaries folder (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6) and added the below lines after the **[mysqld]**. able to see the databases.Please restart the server after making any changes to configuration.

```
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so 
datadir=C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\data
```